# How to send email with ZIP attachments from web server in Python

Tags: python, email, zip, cgi, attachment

I have a question about sending an email with ZIP attachments in Python. Here is how I am doing it:

```
def send_mail(send_from, send_to, subject, text, files=[], server="localhost"):
assert type(send_to)==list
assert type(files)==list

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = send_from
msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
msg['Subject'] = subject

msg.attach( MIMEText(text) )



for f in files:
    remotezip = urllib2.urlopen(f)
    #zipinmemory = io.BytesIO(remotezip.read())
    #zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipinmemory)
    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')



    part.set_payload( remotezip.read())
    Encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(f))
    msg.attach(part)


smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
smtp.starttls()
smtp.login('username','password')
smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
smtp.close()
```

As I have my ZIP file hosted on my web server, I am reading it using URLOpen.

This code successfully sends an email with the attachment. But the ZIP file is always 0KB. Am sure there is some issue in reading the file.

Please let me know. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you try setting `MIMEBase` as `zip`? `part = MIMEBase('application', 'zip')`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes. I tried it. Still getting the same response. The attachment is 0KB.